# jaxrs queryparam not loaded for interceptor

Tags: jax-rs, guice

I have a REST service of the form:

```
@GET
@NeedsInterception
public void getSomething(@QueryParam("xxx") @MyAnnotation String thing) {
    //Stuff
}
```

I then have an interceptor for `@NeedsInterception`.

In it, I perform some logic on the element annotated with `@MyAnnotation`.

However, when the interceptor is called, the `MethodInvocation` object has not yet been resolved with the value of the `QueryParam`, instead it is always `""`;

Is there a way for me to make the interception happen after the `QueryParam` is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which kind of interceptor you are using but a [jax-rs  ReaderInterceptor](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html) is intended to wrap calls to `MessageBodyReader.readFrom`. As you don't send a request body with a `@GET` request this kind of interceptor won't be used.

A [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) should help:

```java
@Provider
public class SomeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String,String> queryParameters = requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you add the query parameters to containerRequestContext, then the parameters should be available in the interceptor by calling getProperty(...) on ReaderInterceptorContext.